# stack and global variables

Tags: c, gcc, stack, global-variables

I have found that moving global variables to local scope saves on stack allocation.

Would savings on stack allocation also improve the performance and speed of the program?
If so, can you give me some formula that shows such improvements?

Comment: You won't find formulae of that nature anywhere. Performance depends on a huge number of factors, and these factors interact. So, there will never be a formula that predicts how performance varies with stack frame size.

Comment: I am not looking for an exact formula, just want to understand how performance is enhanced, even by a little bit, when stack allocation is decreased. Some formula of some sort.

Answer (score 2):

Moving global variables to local scope in fact increases stack allocation requirements. Moving global variables to local scope will reduce the size of the executable. Perhaps that's what you mean.

In general, moving a variable from global scope to local scope, and vice versa probably makes little performance difference. If anything using local scope will have better performance because you will have better cache usage patterns.

However, performance should never be the driving criteria for choosing between global and local scope. Always make that choice based on semantics. Always prefer local scope over global scope, where it is semantically reasonable to do so.

Comment: I tested, and it saves on stack allocation. I tested many versions.

Comment: Adding  local variables increases the size of a function's stack frame. In any case the final paragraph is the important one.

Comment: You are right, but I am using a technique that flattens the whole code. So stack allocation requirements decreases by half. I just need to know about a formula that shows how performance increases when stack allocation decreases.

Comment: Well, first of all we have to understand what you mean by "stack". You must be talking about something else. Adding (and using) local variables will increase the stack frame of a function. So, what do you mean by "stack"?

Comment: Please see gcc -fstack-usage  and that shows you the stack that I am referencing in this question. fstack-usage shows that stack allocation is decreased by half using my technique in coding. Please do not worry about the technique or usefullness. I am asking about a formula that shows how perfromance (response time) is increased when stack allocation is decreased. thank you

Comment: OK, we are talking about the same thing. I am here to tell you that adding and using local variables with automatic storage increases the size of a function's stack frame. Since local variables with automatic storage are stored on the stack, that is obvious.